# How to use Data.List.iterate on tuple

Tags: loops, haskell, tuples

The expression `iterate (1+) 1` evaluates to `[1, 2, 3, ...]`

Can I do something like `iterate ((1+) (1+)) (1, 1)` so I can get `[(1, 1), (2, 2), ... ]` ? If yes, what is the syntax ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax should work fine:

```
iterate (\(x,y) -> (x+1, y+1)) (1, 1)
```

There are also many other ways to skin this cat:

```
iterate (bimap (1+) (1+)) (1, 1)
iterate ((1+) *** (1+)) (1, 1)
map (\x -> (x,x)) $ iterate (1+) 1
join (,) <$> iterate (1+) 1
[(x, x) | x <- [1..]]
```

...and many more.

Comment: Thank you :) That was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Daniel Wagner's answer -- `Data.List`'s `iterate` takes a function as a first argument. The type signature of `iterate` is

```
(a -> a) -> a -> [a]
```

Meaning that the function in the first argument simply has to return the same type as it ingests. This can be an anonymous function, as show in Daniel's answer, or a function name. For example; his example could be rewritten using a named function like so:

```
import Data.List (iterate)

addOne (x, y) = (x + 1, y + 1)
iterate addOne (1, 1)
```